# How to merge classes in multiclass image segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, multiclass-classification

I am performing an image segmentation with a u-net model.
My mask has classes from 0-50.
I also have a text file dictionary with codes representing each class.
For example -

```
{1: '1234', 2:'5678', 3:'1245'} etc.
```

How do I combine when the 2 first string characters are the same so for example above key 1 and 3 are the same because they both start with "12".
How can I do this for all classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
firstTwoCharDict = {}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key == 0:
        value == value
        firstTwoCharDict[key] = value
    else:
        value = value[:2]
        firstTwoCharDict[key] = value
        
newDict = {}

for key, value in firstTwoCharDict.items():
    if value not in newDict:
        newDict[value] = [key]
    else:
        newDict[value].append(key)
```

This provides this

````
{'62': [1, 39],
 '90': [2, 5, 9, 20, 32, 42, 47, 72, 88, 91, 95],
 '97': [3, 49, 55],
 '98': [4, 24, 34, 40, 53, 76, 81, 90, 96],
 '31': [6, 17, 30, 48, 83],
 '69': [7, 13, 15, 16, 27, 44, 51, 54, 56, 75],
 '79': [8, 50],
 '71': [10, 19, 22, 35, 61, 63, 65],
 '99': [11, 12, 21, 46, 52, 69, 78, 84, 89],
 '48': [14, 36, 74],
 '60': [18],
 '64': [23, 38, 66, 97]
```

Now i have an 2d array with integers, how do I replace them with they keys if the array values are equal to the values in the dict?
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).